# parameter_invalid_integer flutter stripe

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

Stripe call fails whenever i pass amount in decimals

```
[log] Payment Intent Body->>> {
```

"error": {

```
"code": "parameter_invalid_integer",
"doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer",

"message": "Invalid integer: 16.99",
"param": "amount",
"request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_i4ON9NcToKANzi?t=1706286148",
"type": "invalid_request_error"
```

}

}

If i give it whole numbers (e.g. 100,200,101, etc) as amount it works fine. I need to make it work for decimals for my app. It is food delivery app and the price for products is in decimals.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Stripe's APIs work.  The amount must be an integer.  If you want to have decimal prices in your Flutter application you will need to multiply them by `100` to convert them to the proper integer value.

The [API reference doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-amount) has a good explanation of this for the `amount` parameter.